# Color dark scheme for ColdFusion/Dreamweaver?

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver, color-scheme

Is there anyone out there who has a dark color scheme for Dreamweaver (CS6) that includes coldFusion Code?

I was not able to find any and changing the colors by hand is really painful

Would be great if you could share one.

Tks

Answer (score 1):

There are colour files for Dreamweaver, but I haven't found any that actually work with Coldfusiun. You can follow this [guides](http://www.thatwebguyblog.com/post/a_dark_code_view_theme_for_dreamweaver/) process. It is a manual process, but it will tell you exactly what to change and as indicated by the latest update at the bottom it does work in CS6.

Copying from link in case link dies. Do note that you will have to go to the link to download the links.

1. Close Dreamweaver
2. Browse to: `%APPDATA%\Adobe\Dreamweaver 9\Configuration\CodeColoring`
3. Rename the Colors.xml file to something different – say Colors2.xml (This will be the file you go back to if you don’t like the new colour scheme)
4. Download and extract the the zip at the end of this article to the location you opened at point 2.
5. Open Dreamweaver and go to Edit/Preferences/Code Colouring and change the default background colour to #003

As a side note. If you are only using Dreamweaver to write Coldfusion, maybe you should consider looking at [CFEclipse](http://cfeclipse.org/). I've found it to be much better than Dreamweaver at writing Coldfusion. Also it's built on top of [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). Which has a plugin to change the colouring. It's also easier to change it manually.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this one already, but it misses ColdFusion and its a difficult task to change manually because 1. directly within the file it is hard to get the right code, 2. editing under >edit >preferences >code coloring makes it hard, as the window is too small and thus you cannot really read what exactly you are editing.

Comment: @suha: Yup. Thats why I recommend rather using CFEclipse. There is no other way in Dreamweaver to change the editor colouring.

Comment: Vincent, just a note to say I've updated the second bullet point - instead of the three different paths you can simply use %APPDATA% to get to those directories on each version of Windows.